# Connect Google Cloud Run to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb-atlas, google-cloud-run

I'm evaluating a move from Google Kubernetes Engine to Google Cloud Run, to improve cost and resource efficiency within our company.  I'm also in the process of transitioning our workflows from monolithic PHP and Ruby apps to a more nimble Node.js setup, using MongoDB.

For a small organization like ours, I like the idea of managed services such as Google Cloud Run and MongoDB Atlas, however, I'm concerned about the security.  In MongoDB Atlas, it seems the only real security measure is to whitelist IP, which I obviously don't have access to through Google Cloud Run.

I'm definitely not a network expert, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas for securely connecting Cloud Run to MongoDB Atlas, while still maintaining scalability.  If I have to remain on GKE, so be it, I just want to know all of my options before I move forward.

IP whitelist - by its very nature, Google Cloud Run would seem to be anti-static-IP, so this seems to be a non-starter.

I evaluated items such as Cloud NAT and Cloud VPC Peering, but from what I can tell Cloud Run does not have access to the VPC, so it seems like this wouldn't help either.

Comment: Cloud Run is expected to get Serverless VPC Access along the lines of https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access. As an alternate document store, you might also consider https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs

Comment: Interesting you ask this question, because we are in EXACTLY the same spot. Except we have Mongo running on a single GCE node and we don't want to deal with the headaches of replication hence the transition to MongoDB Atlas. We also want to use Cloud Run instead of GKE too for our Docker images. The idea of Serverless VPC access is exactly what we're looking for but any ideas @Grayside when that's coming out?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run and Cloud Function have the same underlying infrastructure. Cloud Function have the capability to be connected to a VPC. Thereby, Cloud Run will support a day this capability, I hope by the end of 2019.

If you can, I just recommend you to wait!

Answer (score 0):

**Update (October 2020):** Cloud Run has now launched [VPC egress](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#egress) feature that lets you configure a static IP for outbound requests through Cloud NAT. You can follow [this step by step guide in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) to configure a static IP to connect to MongoDB Atlas.